# Spring Web Application not loading new Servlet

Tags: java, spring, apache, servlets

I am pretty new to Spring and currently working with application built with spring,hibernate and struts. the application itself loads and works correctly but I have been tasked with adapting this application to include an REST API so that the new mobile application can use access the data. The reason they want it as part of the current web app is to make it easier for maintenance.

I have used the http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html to setup the new servlet within the current structure just changing locations of the HelloController.java.

My issues is as follows, when I run the application I get the following output:

M

```
ar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
    INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8090
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 505 ms
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor pmcTracker.xml
    [DevLoader] Starting DevLoader
    [DevLoader] projectdir=/Users/Elliott/TestTracker/root/web
    DEVLOADS all the correct folders and files - cant show due to company material)
    Mar 25, 2015 1:21:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

    Runs a load of hibernate stuff here for the main applications (NOT relevant and correct)

    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8090
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
    INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
    INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/20  config=null
    Mar 25, 2015 1:22:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 11878 ms
```

This does not mention the new added servlet what so ever...?

The main application works fine, but when I go to url for the new servlet it shows a 404 Page not found error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE - with conf files

web.xml contains

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then the config file `springapp-servlet.xml`contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

  <bean name="/hello.htm" class="com.pmc.tracker.api.dashboard.HelloController"/>

</beans>
```

Then the `HelloController.java`contains

```
package com.pmc.tracker.api.dashboard;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning hello view");

        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    }

}
```

Finally the `hello.jsp` contains:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Hello :: Spring Application</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello - Spring Application</h1>
    <p>Greetings.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is then supposed to allow me to enter `www.localhost:8090/pmcTracker/hello.htm`

UPDATE 2 all of web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--
        Fallback locale if no bundles found for browser's preferred locale
    -->
    <!--
        Force a single locale using param-name
        'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale'
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
        <param-value>en</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Context Configuration locations for Spring XML files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/applicationContext-resources.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext-dao.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext-service.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext-activemq.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext-struts.xml           
            classpath*:/applicationContext-scheduler.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
            /WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.oscache.web.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>clickstreamFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.clickstream.ClickstreamFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!--
        <filter> <filter-name>gzipFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
    -->
    <!--
        Remove this filter if you're using iBATIS, use
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter if using JPA
    -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <!--
            <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        -->
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.pmc.framework.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>log4j</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>applicationMenuGeneratorFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.pmc.framework.security.ApplicationMenuGeneratorFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts-cleanup</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>       
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--
        Commented out for 2 reasons: 1) it's a pain when developing JSPs, and
        2) it causes the Signup webtest to fail
    -->
    <!--
        filter-mapping> <filter-name>cacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> </filter-mapping
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>clickstreamFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>applicationMenuGeneratorFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--
        <filter-mapping> <filter-name>gzipFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping>
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts-cleanup</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>                   
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.opensymphony.clickstream.ClickstreamListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.pmc.framework.webapp.listener.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.pmc.framework.webapp.listener.UserCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.sf.navigator.menu.MenuContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

      <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page> 
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/403.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Can you see, because that is part of the frustration I am not if there is one?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to add a new servlet. Instead, add additional mappings to new or existing controllers.

Comment: Post the config where you setup the new servlet and the url that you are trying to hit.

Comment: @minion added some information on config.

Comment: @chrylis so considering the approach above how would I go about mapping?

Comment: What is the main app url mapped to in web.xml?

Comment: I am not sure it is....can you see it? added all of the web.xml @minion